# From Java to C#.Analog of java.util.zip.Inflater from java in C#

Tags: java, c#

I'm trying to translate Java code to C# and find problem with Infater. It's my task with binary work (sorry if it silly question)

Original code:

```
public static byte[] decompressByZLIB(byte[] compressedBytes)
{
    try  
    {
        Inflater inflater = new Inflater();
        inflater.setInput(compressedBytes);

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(compressedBytes.length);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        while(!inflater.finished()) 
        {
            int count = inflater.inflate(buffer);
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }

        byteArrayOutputStream.close();
        return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    } 
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        throw new IllegalStateException(exception.getMessage());
    }
}
```

1. Is Deflatorstream in C# right analog? How I understand deflate and inflate are methods for compression and decompression.
2. In original code mentioned Zlib. How I understand It is what I need.
   I can't use Lib so I tried to understand this file http://www.componentace.com/.NET_zip_component_zipforge.htm, but I think I don't have enough experience to understand how all methods are working.
3. What analog of java ByteArrayOutputStream in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [DeflateStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.deflatestream?view=netcore-3.1) class uses the zlib library so it should work here (I'm not familiar with Java). DeflateStream is a wrapper for another stream that contains compressed data or can receive data. When using DeflateStream you decompress when reading from the stream and compress when writing to the stream.
   Here is an example in .NET Core:

```
        public static byte[] Decompress(byte[] data)
        {
            using (var compressedDataStream = new MemoryStream(data))
            using (var deflateStream = new DeflateStream(compressedDataStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // reading from base stream (compressedDataStream) happens in CopyTo 
                // and decompressed data is copied to outputStream
                deflateStream.CopyTo(outputStream);

                return outputStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
```

2. I don't know the library that you linked. You can search for dotnet libraries on nuget.org. It is default source of NuGets in Visual Studio. You can find SharpZipLib there which has Inflater/Deflater and streams.
3. You should use `System.IO.MemoryStream`. From what I just googled it looks like it combines the functionality of `ByteArrayOutputStream` and `ByteArrayInputStream`.